# Alterar sequence oracle

Tags: oracle

Como faço para atualizar o valor da sequence?

Situação:
Vou criar uma sequence mas pode ser que esta tabela esteja com registro ou sem. Dai como faço para gerar a sequence 0 ou entao com valor a partir de que ja exista registro?

create sequence S_SEG_EXE;

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o `ALTER SEQUENCE`:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE S_SEG_EXE INCREMENT BY 100;
```

No exemplo acima, aumentou em 100 o valor atual da sequence. O valor pode ser negativo também caso queira reduzir o valor.

Comment: mas qual a sintaxe eu posso usar no ligar do valor 100 se eu nao sei qual o valor da sequence atual

Comment: Não sabe como obter o valor de uma sequence? `SELECT S_SEG_EXE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL`

Comment: ficaria assim? ALTER SEQUENCE S_SEG_EXE INCREMENT BY SELECT S_SEG_EXE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL

Comment: `NEXTVAL` não traz o próximo valor? Para obter o valor atual, acho que é melhor usar `CURRVAL`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#i1007824

Comment: Se criar ela nova, você pode definir o valor inicial com `START WITH 0` se quiser começar em zero. Já para alterar para o valor que quiser, use o `alter sequence`

Comment: Sim, @hkotsubo, `CURRVAL` seria melhor: `SELECT S_SEG_EXE.CURRVALFROM DUAL`